# Save Image from res/drawable to Image Gallery Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, drawable, bitmapfactory

I want to Save Image from res/drawable to Image Gallery. I am using following code but it is doing nothing.
What is the wrong with my code ? `String Drawable` stands for Image Name which is there in drawable folder.

```
        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Images");

        if (!direct.exists()) {
            direct.mkdirs();
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    context.getResources(),
                    context.getResources().getIdentifier(
                            "@drawable/" + Drawable, "drawable",
                            context.getPackageName()));

            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, bos);

            byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(direct + "/" + "IMG-" + CurrentDateTime
                    + ".jpg");
            fos.write(bitmapdata);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Internal Image Save Error->", e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (bos != null) {
                    bos.close();
                }
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                    fos.flush();
                }
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
                Log.e("Internal Image Save Error->", ignored.toString());
            }
        }
```

**I just found that it is saving image but It is taking some time like 10 mins.**
Copy Image from Drawable to Gallery : It is giving File Not Found Exception on Input Stream. String Drawable is image name, i.e. data1

```
public static void downloadInternalImage(String Drawable, Context context) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Downloading Image...\nPlease Wait.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Images");

        if (!direct.exists()) {
            direct.mkdirs();
        }

        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;

        try {
            input = new FileInputStream("android.resource://"
                    + context.getPackageName() + "/drawable/" + Drawable + "");
            output = new FileOutputStream(direct + "/" + "IMG-"
                    + CurrentDateTime + ".jpg");

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                output.write(buf, 0, len);
            }

            Toast.makeText(context, "Image Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Internal Image Save Error->", e.toString());

            Toast.makeText(context,
                    "Couldn't Save Image.\nError:" + e.toString() + "",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (input != null) {
                    input.close();
                }
                if (output != null) {
                    output.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
                Log.e("Internal Image Save Error->", ignored.toString());

                Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "Couldn't Save Image.\nError:" + ignored.toString()
                                + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 10 minutes? What is it's size as drawable? And what when saved? Why are you using BitmapFactory? It will change your picture. You can just copy the 'file' using an inputstream and a fileoutputstream.

Comment: `String Drawable stands for Image Name`. That is not a good idea as Drawable is already a class in Android. Better use 'imageName'.

Comment: its size is hardly from 10-30 KB

Comment: I checked some examples and all are using `BitMapFactory`.

Comment: Yes. Can be. But why would you follow bad examples? Do you know what BitmapFactory is doing? You just want to copy a file isn't it? If so than this is bad overkill and the file is different from what you put in the drawable folder. But better concentrate on the 10 minutes.

Comment: I tried copy file but it is saying File not found exception from drawable folder. I have just file name i.e. `data1` then which path should i use ?

Comment: Please show your code in a separate block. |

Comment: That looks ok but for the inputstream. That should be: `input = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.filename);`. And why do you still use `String Drawable`? Arggg..

Comment: It is dynamic and drawable contains many images so I can't use any fix drawable.filename

Comment: You don't understand me and you did not read what I said before. Instead of naming it String Drawable you better name it String pictName. I already told you why.

Comment: yup, got it. I will change it.

Comment: still i cant see any image in gallery.

Comment: What is 'the Gallery' ? You should check with a file explorer app (like ES File Explorer) if it is in the destination folder. The Gallery is just an app and indeed will not yet show the new file. For that you have to do something else yet. But..... You told that your former code took 10 minutes. What do you mean by that? Before it showed up in the Gallery?

Comment: Now, I came to know main issue, I have check image through ESFileExplorer, It is there but it is taking time to display that image in Gallery.

Comment: Yes. I feel sorry that i did not understand your problem before as you indeed were talking about the gallery in the subject already. Now you know that you cannot copy to gallery but to internal, external or removable memory. But you are not the first one with this problem. Please 'google'  this site for this problem and you will find the solution. Its just one line of code you have to add. Sorry don't know from head. Its something with media scanner.